Python logger compressed Time Rotating is possible?
I need my program to write a new log file every day, and so far, that's no problem. However, I also want the files to be compressed once they are written and limited to, for example, 7 compressed files. My only doubt is whether the logger provides a method for automatic compression without having to implement it manually.
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler("my_log.log", when="midnight", interval=1, backupCount=7)


You probably are looking for loguru

Yes I know it  but without loguru?

If so update question specify that and why you need to, we aren't wizard who can read your mind! And have you looked into it's source code how it implements rotation and compression? Since loguru is compatible with logging.handlers I bet reverse-engineering isn't that complex.

It's possible, but not automatically. The Python logging cookbook in the official docs has a recipe for this (using a size-based rotation) which you can adapt for time-based rotation.
